# Google Play says my apk uses two Native Platforms ( my libraries) and so it supports 0 devices

Tags: apk, native, libraries, device

When i publish the .apk on Google Play it says: 0 devices supported. And on the bottom of the apk description it's written: Native Platforms: actionbarsherlock, SherlockNavigatorDrawer. These are the libraries i used for my project. They are not .jars, they are folders i put into the libs folder of the app.
The problem is this: Google Play considers these two libraries as "Native Platforms" (I'm not sure what it exactly means or is), and this causes a filtering in the support of devices. I'm thinking about what can be the causes of this. My project is a collaboration with a friend and the project has been runned and builded several times with eclipse and exported to Aide (Aide is an app that allows you to develop apps with your tablet). Maybe this is only a "path" problem or...? I have the libraries on my lib folder of Aide and i have built the apk there, but maybe some path or something else about libraries remained the ones of eclipse (maybe in eclipse we didn't put the libraries inside the libs folder).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution, and I would like to help all the developers who use Aide. When a library depends on another, like SherlockNavigationDrawer and actionbarsherlock, don't put one in the libs folder of the other, but reference it from an external folder. Same thing with projects and libraries: dont put a library (like ABS for example), in the libs folder of the project, but leave it in an external folder and write a reference to it writing the project.properties file of the project. More than 3900 devices supported now. I hope this will help :-)