# App not compatible with any device in Play Store after migrating to Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility, device

It is the first release after migrating app from eclipse to androïd studio.
Application run perfectly in debug mode but appears in Google Play with no compatible devices.

I am using manifest-merger and the result of the manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.onesoftmob.calc1.free"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="55"
    android:versionName="3.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.DefAnalytics"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconfree"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.Debut"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.Calc"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.Preference"
            android:label="@string/pref_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.PreferenceGenerale"
            android:label="@string/pref_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.AfficheWebView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ImportCalculs"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/import_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.calc1" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Filter to open file with gmail version < 4.2 -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/calc1" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.calc1" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.calc1" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.calc1" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ImportModeles"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/import_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ImportImages"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/import_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.png" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpeg" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.png" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpeg" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ImportXls"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/import_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xls" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.DevisActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ParametresDevisActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ContactManager"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.ListeFichiers"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.SaisieRemTva"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Calc_white" />

        <service
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.MajCurByGvc"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.onesoftmob.calc1.main.CalcProvider"
            android:authorities="com.onesoftmob.calc1.free.auth" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the result on Play Store :

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the generated `build.gradle` files ? How did you import your Eclipse Project into Android Studio ? Try removing the "supported screens" section from manifest. What is the size of your APK ? Play store sometimes does not like APK files over 35mb.

Comment: I think that i have a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155480/google-play-says-my-apk-uses-two-native-platforms-my-libraries-and-so-it-supp

Comment: I solved problem with last releases of commons-codec and commons-logging. Now there are no more native platforms filtering on Google Play.