# Google play, publishing app update, issue with 'Native platforms'

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, publishing

I've a hybrid app to which I've published updates in past. In current update, I've added native facebook login, which required adding facebook jar package under 'libs' folder.
Now, when I add my APK in PlayStore, everything is fine except that Native platforms is being shown striked out (as shown in image). When I compare it with previous version, it shows the same but not striked out. I'm afraid publishing the update would not result in it being available on any devices. Any insights?

[See snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EF56.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use native code in my application. And for it Google Play detects supported architectures by checking `lib\armeabi`, `lib\armeabi-v7a`, `lib\x86` and so on. Can you check is that folders created into your APK?

Comment: There isn't any folder named 'lib' under android platform. Infact, there never was one!

Comment: That's good! I'm afraid Facebook can add it. Can you view your AndroidManifest.xml, that is generated?

Comment: Yes, that does generate. How would I generate an APK then, otherwise! Everything seems fine (as the apk has been tested) except for that 'native platforms' being striked out when adding the apk file on play store. Couldn't find much help anywhere, including stackoverflow. Idk why do people put a negative score on genuine questions! :/

Comment: I don't downvoted your question. I just want to help. There is something wrong with meta-data in APK. So it installs fine, but when Google Play tries to parse it, the problem appears. Using which tool you built an APK?

Comment: cordova via cli? Actually, the app is built on ionic so I used ionic commands (signed and zipped using JDK)

Comment: I think problem is something there. You can check similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155480/google-play-says-my-apk-uses-two-native-platforms-my-libraries-and-so-it-supp

Comment: I don't know cordova well, so I can't help you in details, sorry :(

Comment: Couldn't find any solution so went ahead and published the build. So far, haven't received any issues with installation/download of the app.